# setgid() call in C does not work

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to drop privileges in a C program and whatever I do GID remains 0. After hours of research I am clueless :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <grp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        initgroups("nobody", 65534);
        setresuid(65534,65534,65534);
        setresgid(65534,65534,65534);
        setegid(65534);
        printf("gid: %d\n", getegid());
        execv("/usr/bin/id", argv);

}
```

Returns this:

```
gid: 0
uid=65534(nobody) gid=0(root) groups=65534(nogroup)
```

Why is GID 0 when I explicitly set all three (R,E and SGID) to 65534?

Comment: Because you set UID before setting GID.  You need root provileges, but you threw those away.  Reverse the order of the calls to `setresuid()` and `setresgid()`.

Comment: Also, the `setegid` would be unnecessary too.

Comment: stupid me, yes. The setegid() call was an attempt, I know it is redundant with setresgid(). Thank you!

Comment: Also see [Setuid Demystified](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~bjhua/courses/security/2014/readings/setuid-dem.pdf). Some of those system calls seem to be very platform specific.

Answer (score 2):

To set the GID values, the process needs an effective UID of 0 (root), but your code carefully throws away the root privileges by setting the UID values to 65534 before calling `setresgid()`, so the call fails — as you would have known had you tested the return values of the functions.

Reverse the order of the calls to `setresuid()` and `setresgid()` (and remove the superfluous `setegid()` too, of course, and the extra `printf()`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  // Archaic: shouldn't be needed (but Linux docs list it)
#include <grp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (initgroups("nobody", 65534) == 0 &&
        setresgid(65534, 65534, 65534) == 0 &&
        setresuid(65534, 65534, 65534))
        execv("/usr/bin/id", argv);
    fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

You can be more careful in your error reporting if you wish.  Remember, `execv()` does not return if it is successful; there is no need to test its return value.